# HTML Data not displaying as I want, (PHP array)

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have all my data stored in array's

```
          <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                 <h3 class="box-title">History Page Station Number:        <? php if($_POST){ $id; }?> </h3>
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                                <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table- hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                           <th> Station Name</td>
    <th> Country </th>
    <th> Date </th>
    <th> Timestamp </th>
    <th> Temperature(celcius) </th>
    <th> Rainfall(mm)</th>
    <th> Windspeed(km/h)</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>



    <!-- loop displaying all data -->
    <?php
    if($_POST){

    $cols = 1;
    for ($i=1; $i < count($wind); $i++)
    {

    echo "<tr>";
    for ($c=0; $c<$cols; $c++)
    {
  echo "<td>".$station->name."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$station->country."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$date[$i]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$time[$i]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$temp[$i]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rain[$i]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$wind[$i]."</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";

}

}
?>
</tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> Station Name</td>
<th> Country </th>
<th> Date </th>
<th> Timestamp </th>
<th> Temperature(celcius) </th>
<th> Rainfall(mm)</th>
<th> Windspeed(km/h)</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div><!-- /.box -->
```

When I check the output its displaying element[0] in the first row

```
Element[0] in 2nd row
Element[1] in 3rd
Element[0] in 4
Element[1] in 5
Element[2] in 6 etc
```

it starts at first element again and adds 1.. I dont know what im doing wrong.

I have 22 different elements in my array

Comment: you have an extra space here: `<? php if($_POST){ $id; }?>` first of  all remove that.

Comment: where does `$station->name` and `station->country` come from?

Comment: remove the whole thing, this does not do nothing, or add an `echo` to id.

Comment: no obvious issues with posted code.. May be you wrongly fill your arrays before...

Comment: @cuSK from my Controller. Connects to database and get the country and name of the station

Comment: @rafael you said "**it starts at first element again and adds 1**". Where does the 1 get added? To the index (`$i`) or to the value (`$wind[$i]`)?

Comment: @cuSk it starts with the first element then first,second then first,second,third then first,second,third,forth (http://prntscr.com/55zq2f) watch the timestamps repeating itself. it should be a new row for each second

Comment: @rafael And why are you using that inner for loop **`for($c=0;$c<$cols;$c++)`**? As per that code you are echoing those arrays for only once. So, you can definitely remove that inner for loop. And try whether your page works correctly now?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you are doing your column loop when you declare all your cols in the oner.
ie you don't refer to $c anywhere.
set **$i=0;** initially too.

ie
**for ($i=0; $i < count($wind); $i++)**

Comment: $cols is 1 here, and inner loop does nothing :)

Comment: well, almost nothing.

Comment: thanks for all the feedback, im going to try to figure it out

Comment: how do you populate $date, $time, $temp etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your logic, and i make an example:

U can use foreach :

```
    $weather['name'] = "Local Weather"; //ADD YOUR ROWS AS ARRAY
    $weather['country'] = "Italy"; //ADD YOUR ROWS AS ARRAY
    $weather['date'] = "2014-11-13"; //ADD YOUR ROWS AS ARRAY
    $weather['time'] = "15:20:32"; //ADD YOUR ROWS AS ARRAY
    $weather['temp'] = "18 &deg;C"; //ADD YOUR ROWS AS ARRAY
    $weather['rain'] = "32 mm"; //ADD YOUR ROWS AS ARRAY
    $weather['wind'] = "14 km/h"; //ADD YOUR ROWS AS ARRAY

    foreach ($weather as $val){
        echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$weather['name']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$weather['country']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$weather['date']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$weather['temp']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$weather['rain']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$weather['wind']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: @rafael can you post what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Sure want to see it on teamviewer? 743 726 339 / 6776 I am stuck for like 4 hours now :/